# how do i find all files with the same name in all subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, find, file-globs

I want to find all the different .gitignore files I have to combine them into one.

I tried something like `find */**/.gitignore` but that came up with nothing.

All the files are in sub directories of my current dir, as well as the current directory.

I am using Bash on linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
find -name .gitignore
```

That should do

Since you are using bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
echo **/.gitignore
```

From `man bash`:

```
   globstar
          If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match a
          files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If the pattern is
          followed  by  a /, only directories and subdirectories match.
```

Comment: (a) try it (b) man bash. It sets shell options, this time 'globstar'

Comment: , Shell options? thats a guess

Comment: oh haha, yeah i see, so globstar set allows expansion of ** or something like that?

Comment: `bash: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name`, any idea why it would do this? ( v3.2.39(1))

Comment: How do you fix this error `bash: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name`??

Comment: @Thomas you upgrade bash

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
find /home/user1 -name 'result.out' 2>/dev/null
```

In your case

```
find /<your DIR> -name '*.gitignore' 2>/dev/null
```

This results in

```
/home/user1/result.out
/home/user1/dir1/result.out
/home/user1/dir2/result.out
```